# How can I help the EZIC organization?

Tags: papers-please

What opportunities are there to help the EZIC organization?

Are there any risks to helping them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spoilers below, beware.**

1. You get two pieces of paper, one with lots of symbols and another one with holes. Match the holes using the squares on top of the letter paper to get 2 names of people to let through. By letting at least one through, you get a gift from the Order.

   > Taking the gift will cause the ministry of economy to start investigating you.
2. You are given a poison and some instructions by a member of the Order. You can then kill the person they want you to kill.

   > This will also kill one of the guards.

Comment: Risk of helping: Doing anything to help EZIC will change the game ending. When you're asked to shoot the red guy, it's game over.